# Chrome "Unloading" Stylesheets on Middle Click

Tags: css, google-chrome, styling

We've been having an odd issue that I'm not sure how to tackle, and I think this *may* be related to a recent Google Chrome update, but I'd like some way of sanity checking myself before I open an issue on the bug tracker.

### Problem

We have an internal web application that our users use Google Chrome to access.  Starting sometime early last week, we've noticed that when users middle click links, one or more of our stylesheets gets unapplied to the page.

Weirdly enough, zooming in / out or opening Chrome's Devtools re-applies these stylesheets to the page.  If you open the sources tab in the Devtools and watch the stylesheets that are loaded, when the layout is working, we're seeing the full list of stylesheets.  When a user middle clicks on a link, the stylesheets area flashes and the CSS file is missing from the list.  Zooming in / out re-adds the missing CSS file to that sources list and renders the page correctly.

#### Before Middle Click

[image: Before Middle Click]

#### After Middle Click

[image: After Middle Click]

### Troubleshooting

Thinking this was some JavaScript function doing this, I watched the elements to make sure there weren't any changes to the DOM (thinking we may be adding a class to our wrapper elements on accident).  No DOM changes that I can see, and I'm not seeing inline styles applied to HTML elements.

Figuring that the previous step wasn't enough, I removed all the JavaScript on the page trying to narrow down what file is doing this.  After removing all JS from the page, we're still seeing the same thing.  Someone middle clicks a link, then the page's styles go crazy.

I double checked it in Incognito mode, figuring it was one of my extensions.  It still happens in Incognito mode.

Thinking our Stylus compiler was going nuts, I double checked the stylesheets for any invalid CSS and couldn't find any.  I removed the source maps from all our stylesheets thinking it may be related to that, but it didn't fix the issue either.

I've also checked for the stylesheet being affected having a `disabled` attribute set on it, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

### Wrapup

All in all, I'm not sure what's causing this outside of a browser bug.  This is something that had popped up late last week which coincides with the last upgrade of Google Chrome, which hints to me that this *probably* relates to that update.

That being said I've not seen this issue affect other websites, which also points to the website being the issue so I'm not sure.

Is there any other way I can narrow this down to being a Chrome issue?  I've not had this happen on any other browsers I've tested.  (Working on putting together a MVP of the issue that's happening now.)

Comment: Does this style change happen on `mousedown` or `mouseup`?

Comment: Does middle click perform any action? Are you binding any mousedown, mouseup, click events? Is the user middle-clicking on a hyperlink to open in new tab, or is this same result if they middle-click empty whitespace?

Comment: Has anything gone missing besides `theme-edits.css` after middle click? I see your entire `lib` folder is no longer in the tree.

Comment: @PatrickMoore It seems to be somewhat random as far as what files actually get unloaded.  We're binding click events sure, but this is still happening without any JavaScript loaded or event bound.

Comment: @raina77ow Oddly enough it doesn't seem to be either the `mouseup` or `mousedown` events.  Looking closer at it, it seems to be triggered when the page is loaded on the other tab.

Comment: And the original page doesn't refresh on middle click? Does the console show any JS errors?

Comment: @PatrickMoore The original page doesn't refresh, but it does flash for a second if that makes sense?  I appears it is the page page rendering without the theme edits CSS file, but I'm not 100%.  No JS errors either, this is without any of the JS included on the page.

Comment: I noticed the same issue here on an internal website that I maintain. This internal website makes extensive use of iframes. The CSS file is "lost" when middle-clicking link targets, or during a page refresh. In my testing, the issue was not present on Chrome 52 (Linux and OS X), but showed up in Chrome 53 on both platforms. Today, I received a minor update to Chrome 53 on Fedora 24 Linux [53.0.2785.113 (64-bit)], but the issue remains.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue recently when a dynamic iframe on my page finishes loading. The top window's stylesheets are unloaded until I resize the browser.

Comment: We're seeing something very similar. On a Windows machine the styles are disappearing when opening different tabs. On a mac, the styles would disappear immediately after opening devtools. Reloading in both cases brings them back.  One of our devs pointed out that watching network tab in devtools, the stylesheet has a 304 response with the Initiator listed as Other, on correctly rendered page the Initiator is the page with a 304 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem sounds similar to this.

Chrome Bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647151

Should be fixed shortly.